# Undefined isn't a function (evaluating 't.createContext(!1)') while running react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wrote a mobile app to collect some data from users by using react-native. It uses `react native 0.57.4`, `react 16.2.0`, `react-redux 5.0.5`,`prop-types 15.5.10,`, `react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.11`. I'm also using [this library](https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs) to create survey questions within web-view, i.e., basically nest a webview containing a SurveyJS survey INSIDE a React Native app.
**`Package.JSON`**

```
{
  "name": "SurveyJSInWebViewWithReactAndReactNative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.4",
    "react-native-webview-bridge": "git+https://github.com/abolger/react-native-webview-bridge.git",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "redux": "3.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "22.1.2",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**`app.js`**

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import surveys from './survey/default_surveys';
import Survey from './survey';


const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  onSurveyCompleted(ownProps, nextProps) {
    //TODO: Readers hooks go here.
    alert("Nested Survey was completed!");
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <Survey
        surveyJSON={surveys.example3PagePatientSatisfactionSurvey}
        title="My Custom Survey Title"
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        surveyResponseDateString={''}
        onSurveyComplete={this.onSurveyCompleted}
        data={{}}/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

When I try to run this code in mobile by using `react-native run-android`, I get below error. How can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

only thing missing is binding with context, else i don't see any issue with your piece of code. you can try binding the onSurveyCompleted function with your context. this should work for you

```
onSurveyComplete={this.onSurveyCompleted.bind(this)}
```

either you have to bind method in constructor or while using that in render.

```
constructor(){
   this.onSurveyCompleted = this.onSurveyCompleted.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Not working, I used `constructor` method, getting same error

Answer (score 0):

The new Context API was introduced in react v16.3 and you're using 16.2 so createContext isn't available in your version.

Also, I can't say much about what you're trying to do from the code you shared, but it would be a good idea to build this survey as a standalone web app and then load it remotely into your webview, or even better you should implement this survey in pure react native.